# What are SQL Server Binaries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, binaries

- What are SQL Server Binaries?
- What are some examples of working with this on the job or in practice?

I'm taking a course and this term was casually mentioned, but I'm not sure what it means. Here is an excerpt from the course: "Microsoft keeps images of all supported versions of SQL Server available in Azure Marketplace. If you have a need for an older version, that is covered by an extended support contract, you must install your own SQL Server binaries." Please explain to me like I'm 10. Thank you.

Comment: It means to install it from files. Binaries = setup files.

Comment: Basically there are two types of files: text and binary. Here this is really a reference to the application/installation of SQL Server but the term *binary* applies more broadly than just software executables and libraries. In case it's helpful: that kind of blurb is not likely to be relevant to the task of learning SQL Server itself. You certainly don't want to get overwhelmed by ancillary information.

Comment: See also https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/121224/what-are-binaries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Binaries are the code (in this case, the assembly or machine code).

They are spread across `sqlservr.exe` and `.dll` files.

When it says you "own SQL Server binaries," it means "you own licensed SQL Server binaries."

This implies that you must possess a valid license, which may either be a free edition or a purchased one. Once you have the correct license, you are entitled to download the installer. Executing this installer will deploy all the crucial `.dll` and `.exe` files on your system, thus successfully installing SQL Server. In essence, by completing this process, you have installed the licensed binaries of SQL Server on your device.